# Php project login error

Tags: php, sql, url, authentication, error-handling

Recently i developed  a small school management software everything is fine in localhost but when i move the file to online server and try to login my (role) than it shows me a message and change the url mydomain/authenticate.php

```
The bizedu.co.in page isn’t working

bizedu.co.in is currently unable to handle this request.
500
```

Authenticate.php code here-

```
    <?php

require 'connection.php';
ob_start();

session_start();

$id = "";
$password = "";

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

echo $id . " : " . $password;

$q = 'SELECT * FROM account WHERE id=:id AND password=:password';

$query = $conn->prepare($q);

$query->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':password' => $password));


if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
    header('Location: index.php?err=1');
} else {

    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['role'];

    echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
    session_write_close();

    if ($_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "admin") {
        header('Location: school_admin_home1.php');
    } elseif ($_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "employee") {
        header('Location: school_employee_home.php');
    } elseif ($_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "parent") {
        header('Location: parent_home.php');
    } else {

    }
}
?>
```

Connection.php code here-

```
    <?php
//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','bizeduco_portal ');
define('DBPASS','password123');
define('DBNAME','bizeduco_school');

try {

    //create PDO connection 
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER,  DBPASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

?>
```

Please give me a solution.

Comment: Move source from screens to question. It's comfortable

Comment: Please post the code here. Do you really expect a number of StackOverflow users to type it in themselves so they can debug it for you?

Comment: If you get a 500 message, then your webserver will almost certainly be logging it somewhere. If if doesn't, then its been setup in a very strange way. Those logfiles can probably tell you a lot!

Comment: Copy-paste your code here, each line of your code must start with 4 spaces to be correctly formatted. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help